# if there is an error in 1 file of many files uploading, onprocessfiles() is not called in react-filepond

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filepond

filepond has a callback 'onprocessfiles()' which is called when all the files are done processing, however if there is an error in 1 file of many files, its not called, is there any method to get the error file after all the processing.

I want to remove all the successful file upload from the ui and keep only the error file upload

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

onprocessfiles working only when all files are processed and has status 5. When you have any error which is status 8, onprocessfiles is not firing. Please have a look. According to the documentation each file has own status:

https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/exports/

console.log(files);

If file has an error the status for this will be 8 why do you want to remove files without error from FilePond? I can't understand logic of this.